# Having issues implementing an accordian for dynamically loading divs

Tags: css, jquery

I am working on implementation of an accordian for dynamically loading divs. The issue is the script file having this script & html coding are asynchronously loaded.

```
  $("#leftNavBusinessCounts").append('<div class="SearchDetails"><strong> One-Stop Services  </strong><br></br>View Centers by specific services.</div>');
        $("#leftNavBusinessCounts").append('<div class="sliding-drawer one-stop-details"><h2>Business Services</h2><div>');
        $(xml).find('FilterSection').eq(2).find("FilterItem").each(function() {
             $("#leftNavBusinessCounts").append('<div>HI</div>');
          });
        $("#leftNavBusinessCounts").append('</div></div>');//this is closing even before the <div>HI</div> is loaded ,so its outside.
```

[image]

As you see in the image ,the values are coming outside the accordian ,when i open & close the accordian its empty.The problem is:

The firebug code is like [image]

So I am not sure how the div is closing before. Please see the jquery script & css I am using:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .one-stop-details h2 { 
        display: block; 
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 30px; 
        background-image: url('/COSImages/expanding_section_background_closed.png'); 
        background-position: right; 
        border: 2px solid #ededed; 
        -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
        border-radius: 8px; 
        cursor: pointer; 
        margin: 0px;
    }

    div.sliding-drawer { 
        margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
    }

    .sliding-drawer div {
         display: none; 
         padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sliding-drawer h2').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().children('.sliding-drawer div').slideToggle('slow');
            if ($(this).css("background-image").indexOf('/COSImages/expanding_section_background_closed.png') == -1) {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url('/COSImages/expanding_section_background_closed.png')");
            }
            else {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url('/COSImages/expanding_section_background_open.png')");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Am I missing something important? Thanks.

Comment: you are using `append` wrong for closing your `divs`. It is unnecessary.

Comment: @hunter Even if i remove the div append line its the same issue.     // $("#leftNavBusinessCounts").append('</div></div>');

Answer (score -1):

Try [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for `click` event for the dynamically generated elements

```
$('.sliding-drawer h2').live('click',function () {
```

Comment: you can see there: Categories: Deprecated | Events > Event Handler Attachment

Comment: @AlexandruB. very true ! ! :)

Comment: but the downvoter doesn't know that live() function still works for for jquery version less than 1.7 :)

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." - From the API page for `.live()`

Comment: @jmoerdyk gotcha ! ! +1 for your honesty . . :D

Comment: TypeError: $(".sliding-drawer h2").on is not a function. i am having the .click() function in another page and thts working just fine.